# Implementation of react-intersection-observer module not working on multiple components

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I am struggling with the implementation of the "react-intersection-observer" and i can't for the life of me find a solution.

Details:

I have a simple presentation site which i wanna do with React so i can also learn. Right now the website has only the homepage and the homepage has so far these sections: header, about, portfolio and contact form.

What i wanna do is to simply add a class on each section (about, portfolio and contact form) once the section is in viewport. The kind of stuff that with jquery would be over in 2 minutes.

I have installed "react-intersection-observer" and so far the code in my homepage.component.jsx looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from "../../components/header/header.component";
import About from "../../components/about/about.component";
import PortfolioList from "../../components/portfolio-list/portfolio-list.component";
import ContactForm from "../../components/contact-form/contact-form.component";
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer';

const HomePage = () => {
    const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
        /* Optional options */
        triggerOnce: true,
        threshold: 1,
        onChange: (inView, entry) => {
            console.log("salam");
            console.log(inView);
            console.log(entry);
            if (inView) {
                entry.target.classList.add("in-view");
            }
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <main className="main">
                <About />
                <PortfolioList />
                <ContactForm />
            </main>
        </div>
    );
};


export default HomePage;
```

When i have added ref={ref} on each component like this:

```
<About ref={ref} />
<PortfolioList ref={ref} />
<ContactForm ref={ref} />
```

i have received an error: *Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?*

The thing is that i don't want to add the useInView module in each of the 3 jsx components because it seems bad practice to have repeat code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Passing `ref` as `props` is bad practice**.

Use `React.forwardRef` instead:

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/forwardRef

Check this example:

https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/forwardRef#forwarding-a-ref-through-multiple-components

Comment: Well, it's not a bad practice since it's the ***only way*** to pass a ref to a component, but it's the fact that React function components are "instanceless" and ***require*** the ref to be forwarded.